# Double installations of Android Studio

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I upgraded my Android Studio to 3.1 from 3.0.1 and what I now see is two different install shortcuts (see image below).

How do I deal with this? My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.1

[image: Two Installations of Android Studio]

Comment: You probably can delete the `.desktop` file that's created during installation https://askubuntu.com/q/516207/699350

Answer (score 1):

This was possibly caused by an error during installation but you can find all the Application shortcuts in /usr/share/applications

To delete any of them, launch terminal and do
$ sudo nautilus

Go to /usr/share/applications and delete the icon you no longer need.